# MySQL update only one record

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have a use case at which i need to update only one record based on different conditions, the problem is those conditions retrieve many record,
so the update statement update all of the records every time,

```
UPDATE t_wallet_log wallet_log
LEFT JOIN t_end_user enduser
ON enduser.f_id=wallet_log.f_end_user_id
set wallet_log.f_txn_status = 'successful' 
WHERE enduser.f_ref_number='ugY-227'
AND wallet_log.f_amount=1000
AND wallet_log.f_txn_kind='cr'
```

I tried almost every thing i know but no luck

Comment: is there any transaction request reference that you are storing (which would be unique to the transaction against which you are trying to update the status)?

Comment: @SebastienD: that's the table alias

Comment: @SebastienD, that is not a problem

Comment: Did you try sub query?

Comment: @shaz,No,  we don't have any unique identifier related to transactions

Comment: If you are able to retrieve enduser.f_ref_number from a sub query then use sub query

Comment: @ElhamKohestani, enduser.f_ref_number is Not unique per transactions

Comment: So, is your goal to only update the status of the latest transaction entry that matches `enduser.f_ref_number='ugY-227' AND wallet_log.f_amount=1000 AND wallet_log.f_txn_kind='cr'` ?

Comment: It's really weird to have a LEFT JOIN in an UPDATE

Comment: can't you just use a LIMIT clause?

Comment: Please see my ans

Comment: @Strawberry not so much if it's the same table, but yes here it's strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below query.

```
UPDATE wallet_log set wallet_log.f_txn_status = 'successful' where id=(
select p1.id from ( select wallet_log.id from t_wallet_log wallet_log
LEFT JOIN t_end_user enduser
ON enduser.f_id=wallet_log.f_end_user_id
WHERE enduser.f_ref_number='ugY-227'
AND wallet_log.f_amount=1000
AND wallet_log.f_txn_kind='cr' order by id desc limit 1)p1);
```

This will help you.

Comment: Note that this is an inner join masquerading as a left join. There's also surely more query here than is strictly necessary